# Change value from another form java

Tags: java, variables, static

I have a main form (RandomSend) and another form called (_user)
in the randomsend form I declare a public **static** variable:

```
 public class RandomSend extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 ......
public static String userGender; // this variable I want to change from another form (_user)
....
}
```

and in the RandomSend class I declared _user instance that try to change **userGender** value

```
 _user setGender = new _user();
  setGender.setModalExclusionType(ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
  setGender.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  setGender.setVisible(true);
```

In the _user form (class) I trying to change **userGender** vale:

```
public class _user extends javax.swing.JFrame {......
     ....
     RandomSend.userGender="male";
     ....}
```

when I check the value from within **_user** , the value of RandomSend.userGender is "male"

but from my main form the value is null...

---

**new new**

My attempt According to answer number 1
public class RandomSend extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 *
 */

private static String userGender;
 .....
.....
// show dialogbox to select gender...
 _user setGender = new _user();
  setGender.setModalExclusionType(ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
  setGender.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  setGender.setVisible(true);

....
....

// setter
public static void setUserGender(String gender)
{
    if(gender.toLowerCase().equals("female") ||gender.toLowerCase().equals("male"))
    userGender = gender;
    else userGender= "Unknown!!";
}

//getter
public static String getUserGender()
{
        return userGender;
 }
```

and in the other class (frame) :

```
public class _user extends javax.swing.JFrame {
....
....

RandomSend.setUserGender("male");
..
..
..
}
```

but the Randomsend.userGender doesn't change!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add your question and what you have tried so far to solve your problem, so we know what we can help you with.

Comment: It worked fine for me, you can see the sample [here](http://ideone.com/RrDlfn). There are some issues with your code that you should really try to correct. The formatting I won't touch on as much because that may have messed up pasting here. But a name like `_user` is a bad idea for a class name. Java naming conventions suggest using nouns as names, nouns that are representative of what that class is. And even more so for a subclass of `JFrame`. Something more appropriate (taking wild guesses at your purpose) would be `UserProfileFrame`. tl;dr - I tried your sample and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make changes to an objects member values via the use of getter and setter functions that you define on that object. To use your example you'd end up with something like:

```
public class RandomSend extend javax.swing.JFrame {
    // This should be preferred for values that can mutate (non-final) to prevent
    // modification without the owning class being alerted the value is changing
    private static String userGender;

    public static void setUserGender(String value) {
        userGender = value;
    }

    public static String getUserGender() {
        return userGender;
    }
}
```

Using this example you would change the value by calling `RandomSend.setUserGender("male")` and you would read this value by calling `RandomSend.getUserGender()`.

**Some Additional Notes**

I just wanted to point out some additional things that I noticed about your sample. Using `static` values in the manner that you are is not necessarily the best idea. You're locking the use of the class down in the wrong way. You should maintain an instance of a `User` class or some other kind of class that manages information specific to a user, such as gender. By managing an instance instead of static values on a class you're making it easier for you to handle other users within the application if that need ever rose up. If you are sure you never need to support more than the current user, then you can still use instances but implement it with a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

That would look something like:

```
public class SingletonExample {
    private static SingletonExample instance = null;

    // Declared private to prevent new SingletonExample 
    // outside of this class
    private SingletonExample {} 

    public static SingletonExample getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonExample();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

You would use this class by fetching an instance like `SingletonExample.getInstance()` and then operate on that instance. Using this methods guarantees that in all points in your project you're accessing the same instance of the same object making "global" in a sense.

Another note I would like to make is try and use `final` values or better yet, an `enum` instead of strings for things like gender which you will most likely use as values. I say this because in order to properly compare genders you have to do:

```
if (RandomSend.userGender.equals("male")) {
    // ...
}
```

If you instead created a `Gender` class with constants like:

```
public Gender {
    public static final int MALE = 1;
    public static final int FEMALE = 2;
}
```

And comparisons (provided value changes in the proper classes)

```
if (RandomSend.userGender == Gender.MALE) {
    // ...
}
```

And no more wasted string literals being passed around. This is such a good idea that Java has an entire construct unique to providing this solution called `enum`s. You would define a `Gender` enum like so:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE;
}
```

And then you declare you `userGender` as a `Gender` value and your comparisons are the same as if you built the enum yourself from a class with constant values. These changes can, in the long run, make your projects more manageable and easier to maintain.

Comment: thal u izuriel, really great solution.. and thanks for the additional info.